I’m making a maze generator
So I’m making a maze generator, but the entrance locations don’t add up.
Currently, the entrance markers aren’t on the room tiles, so I’m trying to fix that.
Here’s what I made:


const canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
var dimentions = {
  width: canvas.width,
  height: canvas.height
}
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var open = ['N',"E",'S','W'];
var rooms = 0;
class room {
  constructor(x, y, entrance) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.entrance = entrance;
    this.exit = open[(Math.floor(Math.random() * open.length))]
    while (this.exit == this.entrance) {
      this.exit = open[(Math.floor(Math.random() * open.length))]
    }
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    console.log(this.entrance,this.exit,this.x,this.y);
    drawRoom(this.x,this.y,this.entrance,this.exit)
    rooms+=1;
    if (rooms < 10) {
      newRoom(this.x,this.y,this.exit);
    }
  }
}
function drawRoom(x,y,entrance,exit) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.centerX = (this.x*dimentions.width/10)+dimentions.width/2;
  this.centerY = (this.y*dimentions.height/10)+dimentions.height/2;
  this.size = dimentions.width/10;
  this.entrance = entrance;
  this.exit = exit;
  context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY-this.size/2, dimentions.width / 10, dimentions.height / 10)
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fillRect(this.centerX,this.centerY,1,1)
  if (this.entrance == 'N') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY-this.size/2, this.size, this.size / 10)
  } else if (this.entrance == 'E') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX+this.size/2-this.size/10,this.centerY+this.size/2, this.size / 10, this.size)
  } else if (this.entrance == 'S') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY+this.size/2-this.size/10, this.size, this.size / 10)
  } else if (this.entrance == 'W') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY-this.size/2, this.size / 10, this.size)
  }
}
function newRoom(x, y, exit) {
  //console.log(x,y,exit)
  console.log(y)
  if (exit == 'N') {
    return new room(x, y+1, 'S');
  } else if (exit == 'E') {
    return new room(x+1, y, 'W');
  } else if (exit == 'S') {
    return new room(x, y-1, 'N');
  } else if (exit == 'W') {
    return new room(x-1, y, 'E');
  }
  //console.log(x,67,y,67,exit,67)
}
newRoom(0,0,'N')
<canvas id='Canvas' width='500' height='500'></canvas>



I’m expecting that the entrances (the green rectangles) are where the entrances to the rooms are.
I couldn’t figure out how to format the code properly for Stack Overflow.`

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Please title your questions with a question or the specific issue you are having a problem with so that people who search this knowledge base might find help in your post. I don't think anyone would search for "I'm making a maze generator" and that really doesn't help us understand what problem you are having.

In drawRoom() code for "E", you need to change so the  y parameter has -size not a +size.  Other than that, I would suggest you create and draw one room at a time, one for each of your 4 directions and see if the code draws what you expect. Debug from there.

You must have a map to represent the maze, preferably 2d array. Because you have many "edge" cases to consider when creating a room. Also, this entire approach of randomizing won't be enough but it's a good practice.

I figured  it out:
I just had to change a few + to - and vice versa.
Here’s my new js code:
const canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
var dimentions = {
  width: canvas.width,
  height: canvas.height
}
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var open = ['N',"E",'S','W'];
var rooms = 0;
class room {
  constructor(x, y, entrance) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.entrance = entrance;
    this.exit = open[(Math.floor(Math.random() * open.length))]
    while (this.exit == this.entrance) {
      this.exit = open[(Math.floor(Math.random() * open.length))]
    }
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    console.log(this.entrance,this.exit,this.x,this.y);
    drawRoom(this.x,this.y,this.entrance,this.exit)
    rooms+=1;
    if (rooms < 10) {
      newRoom(this.x,this.y,this.exit);
    }
  }
}
function drawRoom(x,y,entrance,exit) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.centerX = (this.x*dimentions.width/10)+dimentions.width/2;
  this.centerY = (this.y*dimentions.height/10)+dimentions.height/2;
  this.size = dimentions.width/10;
  this.entrance = entrance;
  this.exit = exit;
  context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY-this.size/2, dimentions.width / 10, dimentions.height / 10)
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fillRect(this.centerX,this.centerY,1,1)
  if (this.entrance == 'N') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY-this.size/2, this.size, this.size / 10)
  } else if (this.entrance == 'E') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX+this.size/2-this.size/10,this.centerY-this.size/2, this.size / 10, this.size)
  } else if (this.entrance == 'S') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY+this.size/2-
                     this.size/10, this.size, this.size / 10)
  } else if (this.entrance == 'W') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY-
                     this.size/2, this.size / 10, this.size)
  }
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fillRect(this.centerX,this.centerY,1,1)
  if (this.exit == 'N') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY-this.size/2, this.size, this.size / 10)
  } else if (this.exit == 'E') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX+this.size/2-this.size/10,this.centerY-this.size/2, this.size / 10, this.size)
  } else if (this.exit == 'S') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY+this.size/2-
                     this.size/10, this.size, this.size / 10)
  } else if (this.exit == 'W') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY-
                     this.size/2, this.size / 10, this.size)
  }
}
function newRoom(x, y, exit) {
  console.log(y)
  if (exit == 'N') {
    return new room(x, y-1, 'S');
  } else if (exit == 'E') {
    return new room(x+1, y, 'W');
  } else if (exit == 'S') {
    return new room(x, y+1, 'N');
  } else if (exit == 'W') {
    return new room(x-1, y, 'E');
  }
}
newRoom(0,0,'N')

I spent a bit more time to add some features to my code, such as converting overlapping to junctions and actually making it look normal, but I encountered another issue: for some reason, the array that I added to track the position of the tiles is already full right after I define it. I only changed the drawRoom function:
tiles = [];
console.log(tiles);
var sz = 1;
function drawRoom(x,y,entrance,exit) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.centerX = (this.x*dimentions.width/10)+dimentions.width/2;
  this.centerY = (this.y*dimentions.height/10)+dimentions.height/2;
  this.size = dimentions.width/10;
  this.entrance = entrance;
  this.exit = exit;
  if (tiles.includes((x,y))) {
    console.log('overlap')
    rooms--;
  } else {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY-this.size/2, dimentions.width / 10, dimentions.height / 10)
    tiles.push((x,y));
  }
  console.log((tiles.includes([x,y])))
  context.fillStyle = 'white';

  if (this.entrance == 'N') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/(10/sz),this.centerY-this.size/2, this.size/(5/sz), this.size * 3 / 5)
  } else if (this.entrance == 'E') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/10,this.centerY-this.size/(10/sz), this.size *3 / 5, this.size/(5/sz))
  } else if (this.entrance == 'S') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/(10/sz),this.centerY-
                     this.size/10, this.size/(5/sz), this.size *3 / 5)
  } else if (this.entrance == 'W') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY-
                     this.size/(10/sz), this.size * 3 / 5, this.size/(5/sz))
  }
  if (this.exit == 'N') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/(10/sz),this.centerY-this.size/2, this.size/(5/sz), this.size * 3 / 5)
  } else if (this.exit == 'E') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/10,this.centerY-this.size/(10/sz), this.size *3 / 5, this.size/(5/sz))
  } else if (this.exit == 'S') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/(10/sz),this.centerY-
                     this.size/10, this.size/(5/sz), this.size *3 / 5)
  } else if (this.exit == 'W') {
    context.fillRect(this.centerX-this.size/2,this.centerY-
                     this.size/(10/sz), this.size * 3 / 5, this.size/(5/sz))
  }
}


I'm sorry, but your script is still producing invalid mazes, even if most of the time it results in a valid one. Try running this script multiple times...

Posting a big block of code, with no explanation, isn't really an answer.

I changed some values in the big block of if statements @DavidMakogon
